# HTML range slider color change from red to green according to the input

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I want to create a range slider, in which the color should change automatically from red to green according to the input.

[image]

```js
function getColor(value) {
  //value from 0 to 1
  var hue = ((1 - value) * 120).toString(10);
  return ["hsl(", hue, ",100%,50%)"].join("");
}
var len = 10;
for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
  var value = i / len;
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.textContent = "value=" + value;
  d.style.backgroundColor = getColor(value);
  document.body.appendChild(d);
}

var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: red;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 23px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 0;
  background: url('contrasticon.png');
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 23px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 0;
  background: url('contrasticon.png');
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have done this, "https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWCDS7SHWW1P"

Answer (score 1):

I have replaced the background color with a linear gradient. The opacity is changed by replacing the linear gradient in the background. Hope this helps.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.7));
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.slider:hover {
   background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 128, 0, 1));
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width: 23px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 0;
  background: url('contrasticon.png');
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 23px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 0;
  background: url('contrasticon.png');
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you change the slider, the event `.oninput` is triggered. At the moment the function you have assigned to this event is only updating the text value of `Value:`. I have added the following line to this function:

```
this.style.backgroundColor = getColor(this.value / 100);
```

This will change the background colour of the slider based on its value divided by 100 (e.g. slider value of 40 becomes 0.4, shows green/yellow colour).

```js
function getColor(value) {
  //value from 0 to 1
  var hue = ((1 - value) * 120).toString(10);
  return ["hsl(", hue, ",100%,50%)"].join("");
}
var len = 10;
for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
  var value = i / len;
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.textContent = "value=" + value;
  d.style.backgroundColor = getColor(value);
  document.body.appendChild(d);
}

var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  this.style.backgroundColor = getColor(this.value / 100);
}
//initial trigger so turns the right colour.
slider.oninput();
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: red;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  width: 23px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 0;
  background: url('contrasticon.png');
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 23px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 0;
  background: url('contrasticon.png');
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>
```